# Input button created by SignalR method won't cause jquery click event

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I'm looking to create an add/remove rights sheet for a user. On this page, there is a list of available rights in a list, and another list with their current rights. I want to be able to click a remove button on their current rights and move that right to the available rights. And then be able to click an add button on the available rights to move it to their current rights.

Here's the code

```
$(function ()
    {
        var test = $.connection.testHub;

        test.client.updateAssigned = function (departmentId, departmentName)
        {
            $('#assigned').append("<tr><td>" + departmentName + " (" + departmentId + ")</td><td><input id='" + departmentId + "' type='button' value='Remove' class='btn btn-default' /></td></tr>");
        };

        test.client.updateAvailable = function (departmentId, departmentName) {
            $('#available').append("<tr><td>" + departmentName + " (" + departmentId + ")</td><td><input id='" + departmentId + "' type='button' value='Add' class='btn btn-default' /></td></tr>");
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function ()
        {
            $("input").click(function ()
            {
                var val = $(this).val();
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

                if (val == "Remove")
                {
                    test.server.removeDepartment($('#job').val(), id);
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                }
                if (val == "Add")
                {
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

So the buttons created on page load work perfectly, in that when they are clicked, it removes their table row and moves it to the other table. However, that newly created button does not remove and move to the other side. I'm not sure if this is a limitation where if an HTML tag is created after page load won't be allowed to be selected by jquery? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created your `<input>` tag after adding event handlers to all existing `<input>` tags.

Therefore, you never added any handlers to the new one.

You should call the delegating form of `.on()`, passing a container and a selector that matches children.
[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)